# Exponential generating function question help

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

I have the following formula I am looking to find an explicit formula for the coefficient $ a_n $: here $ a_0 = 1; a_1 = 2 $ for $n\geq2$

$$ a_n = n(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}) $$

define the exponential generating function:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!} $$

multiplying by $ \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and summing over the value for n we get:

$$ \sum_{n\geq2}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n\geq2}na_{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n\geq2}na_{n-2}\frac{x^n}{n!} $$

this gives:

$$f(x) - 2x - 1 = xf(x) + x^2 \sum_{n\geq2}a_{n-2}\frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-1)!} $$

I have kind of hit a dead end here, how do I make the last term on the RHS to make sense? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try $a_n=(n+1)!$

Comment: +1 @JWTanner for the easy way.  If you want to figure out the generating functions, though, note that the term of interest is a first integral of $f $.  So you can e.g. solve a differential equation for $\int f $.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner could you perhaps elaborate a little more on your answer? I think your answer is along the lines of what I am looking for (a simple trick as opposed to integrals/differentials)

Comment: As far as not guessing goes, [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1094844p4898212) shows how one can solve the recurrence by more algebraic means.

Comment: @skidjoe:  it looks like Brian M. Scott basically did already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t see anything better, it doesn’t hurt to gather some data by computing the first few terms $a_n$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
a_n&1&2&6&24&120&720
\end{array}$$

This strongly suggests the conjecture that $a_n=(n+1)!$. Try it: for $n\ge 0$ let $b_n=(n+1)!$. Then $b_0=1=a_0$, $b_1=2=a_1$, and

$$n(b_{n-1}+b_{n-2})=n\big(n!+(n-1)!\big)=n(n+1)(n-1)!=(n+1)!=b_n\;,$$

so by induction $a_n=b_n=(n+1)!$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A little naive question, but how did you get from $ n(n! + (n-1)!) $ to $n(n+1)(n-1)!$?

Comment: @skidjoe: You’re welcome! I rewrote $n!$ as $n(n-1)!$ and factored out the $(n-1)!$.